# Embed YouTube: dimensions

Tags: youtube, wysiwyg

Is it safe to fix the width of an embedded YouTube video and let the height take care of itself?

I have an application where users post notices to a notice board.  The notices are mostly text (with limited html tags) and embedded images.  I am now adding support for embedded YouTube Videos.

The posts come in two different body sizes: 298px and 638px.  When a user wants to embed a video they will go to YouTube.com, find the video, select Share->Embed. They will then copy the iframe code and paste it in to the post they are creating.

Here's an example of the iframe code for a YouTube video:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ny7ysh6y2g0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I am using Redactor for WYSIWYG (http://imperavi.com/redactor/), which makes it easy to update the attributes of uploads and embeds, so I am planning to set the width (to either 298px or 638px), and remove the height.  The few tests that I have done seem to work fine, but I don't fully understand the way that YouTube works with aspect and dimensions.

I *think* that the height will be automatically set using an aspect ratio which is appropriate for viewing (16:9?), but I can be sure without testing heaps of examples.  Is what I am proposing going to give users a good viewing experience?

Comment: When you just put a normal iframe in your page, then youtube has no means of adjusting the size of that iframe element. Browsers apply a default width and height for iframe elements if those are not explicitly specified.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `height` from the `iframe` would not guarantee the correct aspect ratio. As pointed out in the comments, YouTube cannot interact with your page in any way. An `iframe` size is controlled entirely by you and it's content plays no part in its size.

If you wish to resize the `iframe` according to the correct aspect radio, you can use a technique outlined in this post:

[*Embedding a Youtube/Vimeo video with the correct aspect ratio*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20415764/embedding-a-youtube-vimeo-video-with-the-correct-aspect-ratio/29881215#29881215)